# How can I solve C(n,2)+2×C(n,3)+3×C(n,4)+...+(n-1)×C(n,n)=?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients

'm able to find an answer but I don't think it's the right one. I tested it for n=2 and it worked but not for n=3.Here's my answer:

$$C(n,2)+2×C(n,3)+3×C(n,4)+...+(n-1)×C(n,n)=[C(n,2)+C(n,3)+...+C(n,n)] + [0×C(n,2)+1×C(n,3)+2×C(n,4)+...+
(n-2)×C(n,n)] =
2^{(n-2)} + 2^{(n-2)}×(n-2)$$

I'm either forgetting something or it's just fully wrong. Sorry for the bad formatting and thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{r=2}^n(r-1)\binom nr=\sum_{r=2}^nr\binom nr-\underbrace{\sum_{r=2}^n\binom nr}_{(1)}$$

Now for $r\ge1,$ $$r\binom nr=r\cdot\dfrac{n\cdot(n-1)!}{r\cdot(r-1)!\cdot(n-1-(r-1)))!}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=2}^nr\binom nr=n\sum_{r=2}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\sum_{r=2}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}=-\binom{n-1}0+\underbrace{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}m}_{(2)}$$

From $(1),$  $$\sum_{r=2}^n\binom nr=-\binom n0-\binom n1+\underbrace{\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr}_{(3)}$$

Use $\displaystyle(1+1)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk$ for $(2),(3)$

Comment: The OP’s sum starts at $r=2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I've added $$(1-1)\binom n1$$

Comment: But you’re off by $1$, because when you split the summation into two summations, you picked up an extra term in the second summation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thanks for your observation. Please verify

Comment: Looks good now; +1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
n(1 + x)^{n - 1}  - (1 + x)^n & = \left( {\frac{d}{{dx}}(1 + x)^n } \right) - (1 + x)^n  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1} }  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}x^k } \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}(k - x)x^{k-1} } .
\end{align*}
Now just substitute $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a combinatorial approach. As usual, let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

$(k-1)\binom{n}k$ is the number of ways to choose a $k$-element subset of $[n]$ and then mark any one of its elements except the largest. Summing from $k=2$ to $k=n$ gives you the number of ways to choose any subset of $[n]$ with at least $2$ elements and then mark any one of its elements except the largest; that’s the sum that you’re trying to evaluate.

Alternatively, you could carry out the same task by the following procedure.

1. Mark any $k\in[n]$; you can do this in $n$ ways.
2. Pick any subset $A$ of the remaining $[n]\setminus\{k\}$ to get a set $S=A\cup\{k\}$ with one marked element; you can do this in $2^{n-1}$ ways, so there are $n2^{n-1}$ ways to form a subset $S$ of $[n]$ with one marked element.
3. If $k=\max S$, discard $S$, since its marked element is its largest element. By construction $S$ could be any non-empty subset of $[n]$; there are $2^n-1$ such subsets, so we’re discarding $2^n-1$ improperly marked sets $S$.

In the end we have $n2^{n-1}-\left(2^n-1\right)=(n-2)2^{n-1}+1$ suitably marked subsets of $[n]$, so

$$\sum_{k=2}^n(k-1)\binom{n}k=(n-2)2^{n-1}+1\,.$$

For $n=4$, for instance, we have

$$\binom42+2\binom43+3\binom44=6+8+3=17=2\cdot2^3+1\,.$$